# iPhone 11 broken screen needs transferred data to new iPhone

Tags: iphone, restart

I have an iPhone 11 with a broken screen but it still powers on. My data has been successfully installed on the replacement iPhone 11.

How can I do a hard reset on the unusable phone from the replacement phone without erasing the data that was retrieved from the unusable phone? A step-by-step guide would be appreciated.

Can I erase all data from unusable phone without affecting the replacement?

Comment: Why not back up the usable phone so you don’t have to worry about the recovered data? Then you’re free to experiment and not risk further data loss

Answer (score 1):

Taking the broken phone to a computer for a restore is much more practical and likely to succeed. I’ve not seen a reliable iOS tool for commanding another device to erase itself.

Only the side buttons need to work for this procedure

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263